# Jenkins couldn't pull the jar from private artifactory with -SNAPSHOT

Tags: maven, jenkins, artifactory, jfrog-cli

I can build it locally with no problem, but during jenkins build, i am getting error for not able to find the my-app.jar. I do have the SNAPSHOT fold in my artifactory site.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.my.company</groupId>
    <artifactId>my-app</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
</dependency>
```

Once I changed my pom to call the latest jar in the SNAPSHOT folder, everything started to work again.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.my.company</groupId>
    <artifactId>my-app</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-20181204.170129-19</version>
</dependency>
```

Should the artifactory return the latest jar automatically when I use -SNAPSHOT?

Answer (score 0):

The first one should work fine. I guess you have a caching problem. Try to delete the relevant directories from the local repository and try again.